# event.getSource() and event.currentTarget not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

`event.getSource()` and `event.currentTarget` not working in winter 18 please find the below Lightning Component and Lightning controller

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_base_events.htm[image]
**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" >
    <table class="slds-table">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Id</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><a onclick="{!c.editRecord}" data-conId="0037F00000O7Dj7QAF">0037F00000O7Dj7QAF</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td><a onclick="{!c.editRecord}" data-conId="0037F00000O7DjFQAV">0037F00000O7DjFQAV</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td><a onclick="{!c.editRecord}" data-conId="0037F00000O7DjGQAV">0037F00000O7DjGQAV</a></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    editRecord: function (event) {
        var rectarget = event.currentTarget;
        var idstr = rectarget.dataset.conId; 
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": idstr
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

according to [Handling Events with Client-Side Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm) you can skip only `helper` parameter of controller function.

> Each action function takes in three parameters:
>
> 1. cmp—The component to which the controller belongs.
> 2. event—The event
>      that the action is handling.
> 3. helper—The component’s helper, which is
>      **optional**. A helper contains functions that can be reused by any
>      JavaScript code in the component bundle.

Since lockerservice is enabled dataset is not populated directly (for some reason. But you can do it by means of `getAttribute()` function. In this case it is `getAttribute("data-conId")`

Your controller code should look like.

```
({
    editRecord: function (cmp, event) {
        var rectarget = event.currentTarget;
        var idstr = rectarget.getAttribute("data-conId"); 
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": idstr
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If `editRecord` is the controller's method you have to add the component parameter:

```
editRecord: function(component,event,helper)
```

If you only put one parameter you are getting the component but not the event.